# what does here_now(String args0) in Pubnub do?

Tags: java, pubnub

I am trying to find the clients subscribed to a particulair channel. On git I found an example which used a function here_now() with 2 parameters. Something like this:

```
                    pubnub.hereNow(channel, new Callback() {
                    public void successCallback(String channel,Object message) {
                        notifyUser("HERE NOW : " + message);
                    }

                    public void errorCallback(String channel,
                            Object message) {
                        notifyUser("HERE NOW : " + message);
                    }
                    });
```

But in my company's application the here_now() function takes only one parameter i.e a String. I am relatively new to pubnub. Can anyone explain me what this parameter is? is it a channel name? how do I specify the call back functions? I am not able to find any documentation related to here_now(String arg)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the PubNubDemoConsole.java... you can walk through how all the API calls work.

Specifically, for here_now():

https://github.com/pubnub/java/blob/master/java/examples/src/com/pubnub/examples/PubnubDemoConsole.java#L157

(Looks a lot like above :)

You are indeed passing it two arguments. The first is the channel name you want stats for, the second parameter is the callback function to deliver the success or error results on.

Be sure you are on the latest PubNub for Java version as well:

https://github.com/pubnub/java/blob/master/java

If there are additional questions, let us know here, or via support at pubnub.com

geremy

Comment: Hey Geremy... I passed the channel name as the parameter like this:
    JSONArray regarray =  pubnub.here_now("my_channel");
and it worked..it gives me the uuids and the occupancy. why dont we need to specify the callback function here?

Comment: Nemin, can you email me your working code to suppport at pubnub, and we'll take a look?

Comment: And by the way, the only reason I'm asking you to contact us is to narrow down the version you are on. Currently, the only contructor we provide for hereNow is:

        public void hereNow(final String channel, final Callback callback)

So I'm only assuming you are some other version, and we need to isolate that...